# Authentication providers: no token_bearer

Tags: 8

I created a custom resource for a Drupal 8 REST call. For some reason, I can't see either basic_auth or token_bearer from the authentication providers. I installed simple_oauth and still can't see either basic_auth or token_bearer.

> [image]

The code I am using is the following one.

#### config/install/rest.resource.sample_index_resource.yml

```
id: sample_index_resource
plugin_id: sample_index_resource
granularity: resource
configuration:
GET:
  supported_formats:
    - json
  supported_auth:
    - basic_auth
    - cookie
    - token_bearer
```

#### src/Plugin/rest/resource/SampleResource.php

```
/**
 * Provides a Sample Index Resource
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "sample_index_resource",
 *   label = @Translation("Sample Index Resource"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/api/sample-response/{category}/{alias}"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class SampleResource extends ResourceBase {
/**
* Responds to entity GET requests.
* @return \Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse
*/
public function get($category, $alias) {
  // Return response
}
```

The *HTTP Basic Authentication* module needs to be enabled to be able to use *basic_auth* as authentication provider. I don't know which module I should enable to be able to use *token_bearer*.

What module do I need to install to get *token_bearer* as authentication provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your yml syntax is wrong (or out-dated) look at [rest.resource.entity.node.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21rest%21config%21optional%21rest.resource.entity.node.yml/8.2.x) for a correct example.
Or use the "REST UI" module to specify your resources.

It should look more like:

```
configuration:
  methods:
    - GET
    - POST
    - PATCH
    - DELETE
  formats:
    - hal_json
  authentication:
    - basic_auth
```

Comment: Looks interesting. Thanks Rainer. I'll give it a try and will get back to you.

Comment: I didn't know that I needed to enable "HTTP Basic Authentication" module to be able to use "basic_auth". Though, I have changed the syntax as per the updated one. Just looking which module should I use to be able to use "token_bearer" for the authentication providers. Thanks Rainer

Comment: hi rainer, you might know which module should I enable to be able to use "token_bearer"?

Comment: Should work with "Simple Oauth" module - take care for that issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_oauth/issues/2957081

Comment: oh.. got it. Thank you so much for your help Rainer :)